# Enabling Mydomain

Tags: lightning, configuration, mydomain

I am Enabling MyDomain in the prod org and I have few questions that I don't have answers for.

1. The org is using formassembly for web forms. Will there be any disruption to this after enabling mydomain? Also any connection settings to be modified?
2. I did a check the current domain name using CTRL+H in Force.com IDE and saw many of the images in Document are having URL's with the current domain. If I check in salesforce it is nothing more that click, browse and save the image in document. Will this URL's automatically change after enabling mydomain?

Apart from this I have done check for hard code references in the org. Anything more I should be careful of? I have read the document for it and did all check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my suggestions for you.

1. It will not break unless you have hardcoded base URL in any place/custom setting.
2. Yes, they will be changed.

Also, there is a guideline sheet provided by Salesforce. I suggest you check it. it will be helpful for you.

[Guidelines and Best Practices for Implementing My Domain](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_guidelines.htm&type=0)